# How to call a function from the inner class using reflection?

Tags: android, reflection, android-service, accessibility

Using reflection, I'm trying to call the "disableSelf()" function inside AccessibilityManagerService. The function however is placed inside the inner class Service which extends IAccessibilityServiceConnection.Stub. I'm currently getting InvocationTargetException. Here's my code:

```
Class<?> iAccessibilityServiceConnectionClass= Class.forName("android.accessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceConnection");
Class<?> serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");

Class<?>[] classes = iAccessibilityServiceConnectionClass.getDeclaredClasses();
Class<?> stubClass = null;
for (Class c : classes) {
    if (c.getSimpleName().equals("Stub")) {
        stubClass = c;
    }
}


Method asInterfaceMethod = stubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
Method getServiceMethod = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", new Class[]{String.class});

Method getDisableSelf = iAccessibilityServiceConnectionClass.getMethod("disableSelf");
Object getAccesibilityConnectionObject = asInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, getServiceMethod.invoke(serviceManagerClass, "accessibility"));
getDisableSelf.invoke(getAccesibilityConnectionObject);
```

Comment: Note that this sort of thing is starting to be banned on Android P.

Comment: I'm trying to run this on API 25.